# Is there any way to sort a list of Season Year in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to sort an array containing "Spring 2008","Spring 2009", etc.

I know how to do [it](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/~0kniAqbQz-E-BOCf~24DQ) in python. Is there anyway to do it in JavaScript?

```
l = ['Fall 2014', 'Spring 2015', 'Fall 2008', 'Spring 2008', 'Summer 2008', 'Winter 2008']
def key(x):
    seas, year = x.split()
    return -int(year), seas != "Fall", seas != "Summer"
l.sort(key=key)
l.reverse()
print(l)

# OUTPUT : ['Winter 2008', 'Spring 2008', 'Summer 2008', 'Fall 2008', 'Fall 2014', 'Spring 2015']
```

Comment: `Winter 2018` may go before `Summer 2018` if it's 1-Jan-2018 and 1-Jun-2018 or it may go after, if it's 1-Dec-2018 and 1-Jun-2018. How would you deal with that?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue or still looking for solution? Did some of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could split the strings and get the value from an object for the months.

```js
var months = { Spring: 1, Summer: 2, Fall: 3, Winter: 4 },
    data = ['Fall 2014', 'Spring 2015', 'Fall 2008', 'Spring 2008', 'Summer 2008', 'Winter 2008'];
    

data.sort((a, b) => {
    var aa = a.split(' '),
        bb = b.split(' ');
    return aa[1] - bb[1] || months[aa[0]] - months[bb[0]];
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: That one will not produce expected output, though may get quick fixed by `var months = {Winter: 1, Spring: 2, Summer: 3, Fall: 4}`

Answer (score 1):

If we presume that 'Winer' always comes before 'Summer', though it may be the opposite for 1-Jun-2008 and 1-Dec-2008, I would do the following:

```js
const src = ['Fall 2014', 'Spring 2015', 'Fall 2008', 'Spring 2008', 'Summer 2008', 'Winter 2008'];

const seasonToNum = str => ([season, year] = str.split(' '), year+(['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall'].indexOf(season)+1)/4);

const res = src.sort((a,b) => seasonToNum(a) - seasonToNum(b));

console.log(res);
```